# alertdialog - removeView has to get called

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have a alert dialog with a editText area. When I call it a second time, the app crashes with error:

```
02-28 23:25:08.958: E/AndroidRuntime(11533): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my code:

```
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    String txt_title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.txt_head_search_coord);
    String txt_message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.txt_mess_search_coord);
    alert.setTitle(txt_title);
    alert.setMessage(txt_message);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();

            // Do something with value!

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    //UTM Koordinate suchen
    btn_search_coord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

the alert is defined globally so I can call it in the onClickListener

I'm already dismissing my dialog...

Comment: what line is causing the crash

Comment: in the line where i call alert.show();

Comment: does it occurs when you click on the button twice ?

Comment: yes, on the first call it works, on the second it crashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AlertDialog.Builder.show` create a **new** instance of `Alert` from the content of the `Builder`, including the view given in `setView`.

Therefore, your `input` will be added to both the `alerts`. To prevent this, use `create` to create a final instance of your `AlertDialog` and call `show` on this one:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

[...]
// in onClick
alertDialog.show();
```

On a broader perspective, you should use `showDialog(int id)` and the associated methods `onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog`. However, all this is now deprecated if you use `Fragments`, in which case you should use a `DialogFragment`