# alertdialog - is it cool way make new alertdialog when popup this?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107128/alertdialog-removeview-has-to-get-called/22107270#22107270)

making android app, I think my code is not cool.

Because, **I make new AlderDialog.Builder whenever needs dialog** to prevent this error

*"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."*

my code is here

```
mDisposable.add(
    RxView.clicks(fabTodoAdd).subscribe(aVoid -> {
      initBuilder();
      builder.show();
    })
);

private void initBuilder() {
  if (getActivity() != null) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Add Your Todo");
    builderInput = new EditText(getActivity());
    builderInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(builderInput);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> builderInput.getText());
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
  }
}
```

is there any way make only one time builder, and call not (init, show) but only show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple way to make dialog with custom layout:
Please review the code below:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_news_description);//Your custom layout
    TextView sometextview = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);// Textview in your custom layout
    Button somebutton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_done);// Button in your layout
    somebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//on button click listener
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //DO your job.... 
            //then...
            dialog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```